# Blueimp gallery not working in angularness when I enable html5mode

Tags: angularjs, blueimp, angular-routing

I am building my first angular app and everything was going well until I wanted to remove the "#" from the URL.
So far I have built the following:

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('mosaic', ['ngRoute', 'appServices', 'appControllers', 'appDirectives']);
var appServices = angular.module('appServices', []);
var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);
var appDirectives = angular.module('appDirectives', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'http://54.67.25.157/login',
        controller: 'AuthenticationController'
    }).
    when('/activate', {
        templateUrl: 'http://54.67.25.157/activate'
    }).
    when('/mosaic', {
        templateUrl: 'http://54.67.25.157/mosaic',
        access: { requiredAuthentication: true }
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
            //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            //$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
}]);


app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('TokenInterceptor');
});

app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $window, AuthenticationService) {
     $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, nextRoute, currentRoute) {
    if(nextRoute != null && nextRoute.access != null && nextRoute.access.requiredAuthentication 
    && !AuthenticationService.isAuthenticated && !$window.sessionStorage.token) {
        $location.path("/");
    }
  });
});
```

Here is my html file:

```
<body style="" class="ng-scope" ng-app="mosaic">
  <!-- ngView:  --><div class="container ng-scope" ng-view=""><h4 class="ng-scope"> Hi ABC, </h4>
<div style="height: 402px;" class="ng-scope justified-gallery" id="links" gallery="">


  <a style="width: 300px; height: 400px; top: 1px; left: 1px; opacity: 1;" href="/media/DPMosaic_jmJyQrc.jpg" class="justified-gallery jg-entry" ng-href="/media/DPMosaic_jmJyQrc.jpg" title="./DPMosaic_jmJyQrc.jpg" data-gallery="">
    <img style="width: 300px; height: 400px; margin-left: -150px; margin-top: -200px;" src="/media/DP_thumbnail_Ktojkqa.jpg">
  <div style="opacity: 0; display: block;" class="caption">./DPMosaic_jmJyQrc.jpg</div></a>



  <a style="width: 533px; height: 400px; top: 1px; left: 302px; opacity: 1;" href="/media/testMosaic_5HF2z0K.jpg" class="justified-gallery jg-entry" ng-href="/media/testMosaic_5HF2z0K.jpg" title="./testMosaic_5HF2z0K.jpg" data-gallery="">
    <img style="width: 533px; height: 400px; margin-left: -266.5px; margin-top: -200px;" src="/media/test_thumbnail_ng2FmDO.jpg">
  <div style="opacity: 0; display: block;" class="caption">./testMosaic_5HF2z0K.jpg</div></a>


</div>
```

I have defined the justified gallery directive and the entire set up works fine until I uncomment 2 lines in app.js
The 2 lines are:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

The head section of the HTML contains base href="/" as well. 
I did this to remove the "#" in the URL and the app which was working fine stopped working. 
By stopped working, I mean when I click on the image link in the html, it used to open the gallery in a carousel. After including the above lines I get redirected back to my home page with the following error on my firefox console.

> blueimp Gallery: No or empty list provided as first argument." Object
>   { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → 54.67.25.157,
>   selector: "[data-gallery=""]

I am new to AngularJS and have no idea what might have gone wrong. Please help me. 
If you want other details about the application, please let me know. The application is hosted at http://54.67.25.157/account

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this directive:

```
;(function(
  angular, $
) {
  'use-strict';
  angular.module('mosaic').directive('a', [
    function blueImpFix() {
      function prevent(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      function unprevent() {
        $(this).unbind('click', prevent);
      }
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          if('gallery' in attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', prevent).on('$destroy', unprevent);
          }
          return elem;
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
})(
  window.angular,
  window.jQuery
);
```

Answer (score 1):

A more concise version of the solution above.

Set an ng-click on the a tag where you set data-gallery=""

```
  <a ng-click="handleClick($event)" style="width: 300px; height: 400px; top: 1px; left: 1px; opacity: 1;" href="/media/DPMosaic_jmJyQrc.jpg" class="justified-gallery jg-entry" ng-href="/media/DPMosaic_jmJyQrc.jpg" title="./DPMosaic_jmJyQrc.jpg" data-gallery="" >
```

then prevent event propagation in the controller/directive:

```
$scope.handleClick = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
};
```